# My flatbreads are still doughy inside after cooking?

Tags: bread, flatbread, griddle

So I am making basic flat breads using flour, water, oil, salt and spices. I kneaded the dough for 5 mins and rested it for 15.

I then rolled them out really thin and cooked on a super hot griddle, two minutes per side. Once they are charred, though, they are still doughy inside. Are they meant to be doughy? I was expecting something pitta-esqe.

Comment: You might've cooked the first side too long -- I think you want to just barely cook it, then flip.  (if you cook the middle through, it won't turn into a 'pocket pita').  You might also try the oven, as you'll get better puff in there.

Comment: You also need to roll pitas quite thin.  I personally prefer more naan-like flatbreads, and stretch mine ... sear on a hot griddle, then into a medium oven to finish cooking (while I keep making more)

Comment: Maybe "super-hot" is a bit too hot?

Comment: While you can make flatbread without letting the dough rest, 30 minutes or more will make the dough more elastic. To have any chance of a pocket on a bread with no leavening, you need to stretch and fold the dough before forming the final balls that you roll out.

Comment: What kind of flat bread are you going for? More like a tortilla or more like naan?

Answer (score 3):

Your list of ingredients doesn't contain any kind of leavening agent. A leavening agent is an ingredient that helps to incorporate air and gas bubbles into the dough of the product. Without that inclusion of air bubbles, the dough doesn't have anything to lift it and make it lighter, so it will fall and become heavy, doughy and sad.

In many traditional flatbread recipes, such as Pita or Naan, the leavening agent is yeast. However, yeast-raised breads can be incredibly time consuming. That's why In some simple recipes it is possible to use baking powder or self-raising flour (which is basically flour mixed with baking powder) in the place of yeast, but know that this will cause a large difference in flavor and texture from the more traditional yeast-raised breads

In short, you'll need to amend your recipe to include one of the basic leavening agents. Here's a couple basic recipes for you, in case you need some inspiration. c:

http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/bread-recipes/easy-flatbreads/#s5UQEEaz0CUakBp9.97
http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/homemade-flat-bread-recipe2.html
http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Peppys-Pita-Bread/Detail.aspx?evt19=1

Comment: There are unleavened flatbreads too. If this is what the OP wants to make, then adding a leavening agent will be counterproductive. Although you are right that, if he expects "something pittaesque", he should make them with yeast - neither an unleavened bread nor a baking powder leavened bread would have a texture similar to a pita.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same recipe, as I was looking for one without yeast. I cooked the pitas on a pan for 1-2 minutes on both sides, then placed them in the oven to cook. I did not turn them in the oven, simply placed them under the broiler for 1-3 minutes. They inflated properly, but when opened, one layer of the pita was super thin (the layer that inflated) while the other layer (you could say the bottom) remained thick and doughy, almost uncooked. My pitas ended up being under cooked, and I believe the reason for the doughy part is either from a. Having too thick pieces of dough/bread or b. not rotating the pitas in the oven, or not baking both sides evenly.
I made a second batch, added more water to the dough, rolled them out thinner and cooked them the same way. Though the bread was better, there was still the issue of the doughy part. That I believe can be solved by cooking both sides evenly, in my case by rotating them in the oven. Learn from my mistakes!

Comment: *I believe can be solved* **Did** you actually solve it?